# How do you clear the saved instance data?

Tags: android, android-activity

In an activity's onCreate, you get passed a savedInstanceState Bundle, how can you clear that data?
I'm referring not to the Bundle you're getting itself, but to the data this Bundle is created/loaded from by Android.

This would be an occasional clear, and I don't want to clear any of the rest of the app's data (ie. it shouldn't clear preferences, db, etc.).

I'm considering falling back to having a flag and logic to conditionally ignore the saved state, but that sounds clumsier than just clearing the saved state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* just pass null into `super.onCreate(null)` - savedInstanceState is the saved state of the activity instance and (probably) doesn't contain preferences or persistent data.

I'm not sure why you would want to ignore the sIS - for example, if the user was typing into an EditText, switches to another app and comes back later, you'd lose the text they already entered.

Comment: That would be ignoring the state, not clearing it. Amidst the state there is a WebView state, and upon user request, I want this state cleared. So it wouldn't be dropped all the time for random switches, just once in a while, after the user asked for it, all the other times I want the state preserved (along with the rest of the app settings and data, so "clear data" is no option).

Comment: I think you are confusing the persistent state of a WebView as the sIS - if you finish an activity and restart it, sIS will be null, yet the WebView can still remember form data, passwords, cookies, etc (which are cleared when you 'clear data'). But there are methods on WebView and its associated classes which can clear this data without killing the preferences & other data

Comment: Hmm, yes, I didn't know that. Is there a way to clear that WebView data even when the WebView isn't instantiated/accessible (as from another Activity in the same app)?

Comment: Yes, `WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAll()` will delete the local storage used by JS, and `CookieManager.getInstance(). removeAllCookie ()` will clear the cookies. Each of those have methods to delete specific bits of data if you don't want to clear it all.